# A four word phrase (ends with k)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, visual, flags

The flags/objects you see are currently in disorder.
Place them in correct order and provide an explanation for all the flags/objects and give me the answer I'm looking for.

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing flag is:

> [image: French flag]
>
>  The flag of **France**.

Because the desired sequence of objects here is:

> [image: Flags in sequence]
>
>  (or with the last flag at the start, depending on your preference...)

As these represent:

> **Mo**ldova
>  **Tu**rkey
>  (no valid country flag)
>  **Th**ailand
>  **Fr**ance
>  **Sa**n Marino
>  **Su**riname

Which hints at our desired four-word phrase ending in 'k':

> **DAYS OF THE WEEK** - since these flags represents nations who share their first 2 letters with the name of a day in English (**Mo**nday, **Tu**esday, *Wednesday*, **Th**ursday, **Fr**iday, **Sa**turday, **Su**nday. The 'X' takes the 'Wednesday' position in the sequence since there are no independent sovereign states in the world whose name begins with 'W' (let alone 'We').
>
>  (Note: France is our only option for the Friday position, since the only other 2 sovereign states beginning with 'F' are Fiji and Finland, which do not have 'r' as their second letter...)

Comment: Everything as intended. Well done!